# Does mimetools.py module working on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I got this error message ..

what is the problem ?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/webapp/__init__.py", line 517, in __call__
    handler.post(*groups)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/refacingme/1.348883430619943894/main.py", line 187, in post
    upload_pic(profile["id"], user["access_token"], "test", "test.jpeg", image_source)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/refacingme/1.348883430619943894/main.py", line 320, in upload_pic
    form = MultiPartForm()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/refacingme/1.348883430619943894/main.py", line 215, in __init__
    self.boundary = mimetools.choose_boundary()
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_dist/lib/python2.5/mimetools.py", line 131, in choose_boundary
    hostid = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'gethostbyname'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `socket` library is not supported under AppEngine. [See the docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime.html#Pure_Python).

Comment: yes, but how he used it here http://rationalpie.wordpress.com/2011/02/12/posting-photo-to-wall-using-facebook-graph-api/

Comment: I'm sorry, but that address is filtered on my current internet connection, so I can't see what you are talking about.

Comment: @adham The code in that article is not part of an App Engine app.